# how to access Macbook Pro hard drive after network boot (OptCmd-R)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, startup, crash

My mac won't boot.
I need to re-install OS.
But hard disk is too full, so I need to delete some files.
I boot Opt-Cmd-R then open menu > Utilities > Terminal

but bash shell only shows boot partition files.

How can I access the main hard drive, so I can delete some files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197503/how-can-i-delete-files-in-recovery-mode-using-terminal-on-my-os-x-main-partition)

**NOTE**: I am assuming you are in recovery already.

Commands are `like this`.

1. Open Terminal from the menu bar (under Utilities)
2. Change directory: `cd /Volumes`
3. List all volumes: `ls`
4. Change to the volume you want to access. For example, usually the Mac disk is called "Macintosh HD". So, you would do, `cd "Macintosh HD"`. Replace "Macintosh HD" with the name of your drive
5. At this point, you can see all files like you would normally.

Comment: I then went into my Downloads folder and deleted 6GB worth of unused files.

Comment: Was your Mac able to boot after this?

Answer (score 0):

My hard disk is at /Volumes/.

I just saw elsewhere on apple.stackexchange.net 
[solution](http://I%20just%20saw%20elsewhere%20on%20apple.stackexchange.net)
[How to copy files from an unbootable Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56409/how-to-copy-files-from-an-unbootable-mac)